# facebook private message using url

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

i'm doing simple android project using phonegap. I have to send private message to my friends in facebook from my application. Is there any way to send message through Url?

Answer (score 1):

Until recently Facebook didn't support the send dialogue on mobile, so you couldn't do that.

With their push of Facebook messenger, they started supporting private messages on mobile - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#message-dialog

Not idea if there's a PhoneGap plugin that supports it, I'm looking for one as well...

Answer (score 0):

Check Direct URL Example section in [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) page

> [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&
>   name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&
>   link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&
>   redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&%20name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&%20link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&%20redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response)

This is a sample link given in documentation.

Comment: In iPhone, this does not work. It says: 'This dialog is not available on this device. API error code: 4202'.

Comment: try changing display mode to touch. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

Comment: Same problem here. Display mode changes do not help, unfortunately :[

Answer (score 0):

On m.facebook.com, no display is needed, nor is any other display than 'touch' allowed as we always default to 'touch'.
So that doesn't seem to solve the problem.
Facebook says it's a bug by design https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/507406422635550?browse=search_511bd57f912f84e18364257